# Looping through powerpoint slides to write data based on slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm a beginner at using Excel vba, but I got lost during some tasks, what I want and couldn't do is:

Is check for the first row in excel for example and see how many values I have and based on that, I want to loop through the slides and create shapes based on the number of values of the row from excel, 3 values first row then three shapes, 5 values then 5 shapes will be created or look for a slide that has 5 shapes (If a slide is already defined and has 5 shapes) and write there.

so slide 1 has 3 shapes based on 3 values, and slide 2 had 5 shapes based on 5 values and so on..

I already can print all the values, but what I want is be able to print shapes based on the number of values, so if I have 3 values then 3 shapes will be used, 6 values 6 shapes and like that. Let's assume that a slide has 4 shapes and I had 5 values or 3 or whatever, if it doesn't match, it will look for another slide that has the same amount of shapes as values.

**my code: (Sample Code)**

```
 Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim oPPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
 Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub wrtite_service()


Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g As String


Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue


Set oPPTPres = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\aaaa.pptx")
Count = 1

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

If Count > 0 Then

   
 Cells.Find(What:="A", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 a = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value
   
 Cells.Find(What:="B", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 b = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value
   
 Cells.Find(What:="C", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 c = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value

 Cells.Find(What:="D", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 d = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value
 
 Cells.Find(What:="E", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 e = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value

 Cells.Find(What:="F", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 f = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value

 Cells.Find(What:="G", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                 g = ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value

 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("a")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = a
          
  End With

 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("b")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = b
          
  End With
 
 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("c")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = c
          
  End With

 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("d")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = d
          
  End With
                          
 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("e")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = e
          
  End With
   
 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("f")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = f
          
  End With
   
 Set oPPTShape = oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("g")

 With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = g
          
  End With
  
 Count = Count + 1
 End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

values of excel

[image]

first-row value to powerpoint slide

[image]

second-row value to powerpoint slide

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code *as text*.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as a picture and explain what's not working the way you expect it to.

Comment: Check now please

Comment: If you declare `Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g As String` only `g` is a `String` but all the others are of type `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim a As String, b As String, c As String, d As String, e As String, f As String, g As String`

Comment: I did that now, but even before It was working.

Comment: Isn't a a variable?  Why do you have oPPTPres.Slides(Count).Shapes("a"), where a is in double quotes?

Comment: "a" is the shapes name in the PowerPoint file that I'm working with.